# angularjs - ng-repeat doesn't iterate over hashmap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate over hashmap like this:

index.html

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
        <p>Your Data:</p>
        <ul ng-repeat="(name, person) in data">
              name: {{name}}
            --------------------------
                age: {{person.age}}
                hair: {person.hair}}

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my ClickToEditCtrl.js

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data =[];
    $scope.data["Mike"] = new person (11,"blonde");
    $scope.data["Dan"] = new person (22, "redhead");
}

function person(age, hair){
  this.age = age;
  this.hair = hair;
}
```

that doesn't work..

I am getting empty list.

what am I doning wrong?

thanks!

Comment: what does your $scope.data look like when you console.log it? Say if you do it after you add the Dan person.

Comment: it has a hashmap like I would expect with the dan as key and person object as value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing new array instead of object.
It should be `$scope.data = {};` instead of `$scope.data =[];`

And you'd better put `ng-repeat` on `li` rather than `ul`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(name, person) in data">

    name: {{name}}
    --------------------------
    age: {{person.age}}
    hair: {{person.hair}}
  </li>
</ul>
```